# RecyclerView NotifyItemInserted

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView.Adapter` with `hasStableIds(true);` and a `LinearLayoutManager` with `reverseLayout(true);`

I insert a new item to the object list in the adapter then call `NotifyItemInserted(0)`. The list is reversed and loads from bottom to top with the `new item` always at the bottom.

The problem is when calling `NotifyItemInserted` all of the ViewHolders are "Refreshed" / "Reloaded" / "Recreated" - The viewholders are a bit complex and do not want them all to be recreated each time.

When I debug the solution, `OnBindViewHolder` starts from position 0 (Which is correct) then goes up to position 10 or 11 depending on how many items there are on screen, recreating them all.

I have tried many different settings on the `adapter`, `layoutmanager` and the `recyclerview` itself which none of them work.

I see there is a payload which can be passed in `NotifyItemChanged` but not in `NotifyItemInserted`. Maybe with the payload I can check whether the item is already on screen and don't recreate it again, I don't know what to do.

I am using Xamarin.Android but that should not be a problem here.

Comment: Instead of using notifyItemInserted(0), try using notifyItemInserted(position)

Comment: You insert the new item in position 0 and then you reverse the list and you put it last? Is this correct?

Comment: @mTak Well, the new items are always in position 0. The list of objects is reversed in itself and the recyclerview displays items from bottom to top.

Comment: @MehulKanzariya I have tried notifyItemInserted(list.Length) without any luck

Comment: @Pierre Before called notifyItemInserted, are you added that row to the arraylist?

Comment: @MehulKanzariya That is correct

Comment: Try removing the `hasStableIds(true);`.

Comment: @MehulKanzariya I do add items to the end of the list and then call `recyclerView.adapter.notifyItemInserted(myList.size - 1)` and it works fine. What are you talking about?

Comment: @HedShafran That actually worked. Do you know why it recreates all viewholders when it is set to true?

Comment: Yes.. I'll write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `hasStableIds(true)` should solve your problem.

**Reason:**

When you set `hasStableIds` to `true`, the `Adapter` assumes that every item has a unique id, and it uses the values returned from the `getItemId(int position)` method to animate data changes for you.

That's an easy way to animate changes without any effort (As long as the `getItemId(int position)` really returns a unique id per item, otherwise you'll crash).

But in your case you want to animate changes by yourself and control which items will be re-rendered and which will not.